# How to add 8 hours to a datetime with managing day change cases

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this code which is derived from RAW datetime string. I just used substring to place it in order. Now I'm having some problem adding 8 hours to the date and time.

Take a look at my code. It says

> 'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'blkblk'

Code:

```
string hour = datetime.Substring(0,2);
string minutes = datetime.Substring(2,2);
string seconds = datetime.Substring(4, 2);
string day = datetime.Substring(6, 2);
string month = datetime.Substring(8, 2);
string year = datetime.Substring(10, 2);
string strdate = "20" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " ";
string strtime = hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ".000";
string findatetime = strdate + strtime;
//Convert date END

txtbxDateTimeActive.Text = findatetime;
DateTime blkblk = Convert.ToDateTime(findatetime);
DateTime otherDate = DateTime.blkblk.AddHours(8);
string blabla = Convert.ToString(otherDate);
MessageBox.Show(blabla);
```

Comment: `DateTime otherDate = blkblk.AddHours(8);`

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. I made this one. `DateTime blkblk = Convert.ToDateTime(findatetime).AddHours(8);`

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime otherDate = blkblk.AddHours(8);
```